# Копирование Handle окна используя клавиатуру

Tags: delphi, delphi-7, delphi-xe, delphi-xe5, delphi-xe7

Получаю **Handle окна другой программы** при наведении **курсора мышки** на форму (то есть форму другой программы). И вывожу его в **LabelHandle.Caption**.

**Интересует ответ на вопрос:** Как, при нажатии на клавиатуре, комбинации **ctrl + C** скопировать в буфер **Handle**.

```
procedure TForm1.Timer1Timer(Sender: TObject);
var
  Wnd: HWND;                   // Hahdle найденного окна
  Pos: TPoint;                 // Позиция курсора
  Rect: TRect;                 // Координаты окна
  buff: array[0..255] of char; // Буфер
  WndText: string;             // Текст окна
  NameClass: string;           // Класс окна
begin
   // Получаем позицию курсора
   GetCursorPos( Pos );
   // Получаем Handle окна под курсором
   Wnd := WindowFromPoint( Pos );
   GetWindowRect( Wnd, Rect );
   GetWindowText( Wnd, buff, SizeOf( buff ) );
   WndText := StrPas( buff );
   GetClassName( Wnd, buff, SizeOf( buff ) );
   NameClass := StrPas( buff );

   LabelHandle.Caption := 'Handle: ' + IntToStr( Wnd );
   LabelName.Caption := 'Name: ' + WndText;
   LabelClass.Caption := 'Class: ' + NameClass;
end;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Если это должна быть замена таймера, то выполняем следующие шаги.

Пишем функцию.

```
function GetHandle: Integer;
var
  Pos: TPoint;                 // Позиция курсора
begin
   // Получаем позицию курсора
   GetCursorPos( Pos );
   // Получаем Handle окна под курсором
   Result := WindowFromPoint( Pos );
end;
```

Устанавливаем перехват формой нажатие клавиш.

```
KeyPreview := True
```

Пишем событие `KeyDown` с проверкой на нужные клавиши и копированием в буфер.

```
uses
  Vcl.Clipbrd;

procedure TForm1.FormKeyDown(Sender: TObject; var Key: Word; Shift: TShiftState);
begin
  if (Shift = [ssCtrl]) and (key = Ord('C')) then
    Clipboard.AsText := IntToStr(GetHandle);
end;
```

Все это будет работать, только когда окно активно. Если требуется чтобы это работало с фокусом на любом окне, то надо использовать виндовые хуки.

<s>Самый простой способ это выводить не в `LabelHandle.Caption`, а использовать `TEdit`, в этом случае `CTRL+C` будет работать из коробки, так сказать.</s>

Comment: Я переделала но получается что при нажатии CTRL + C когда курсор мышки на другой форме - ничего не копируется в буфер. То есть EditHandle.Text не копируется в буфер.

Comment: Это ответ не на тот вопрос. Вопрос в том, как получить хендл окна под курсором и сохранить его в буфер используя хоткей, а не просто как скопировать некий текст и эдита в буфер.

Comment: @zed из вопроса это не следует, т.к. в текущем коде из окна его не скопировать тоже.

Comment: Следует. Перечитайте вопрос и код ещё раз. Сейчас хендл копируется по таймеру, а надо по хоткею. И надо не в лейбу, а в буфер. Задача из двух частей.

Comment: @Татьяна новый ответ.

Comment: @zed не следует! Вопрос поставлен: Получаю, Вывожу, Как скопировать. А должно быть: Получаю, Вывожу, Как заменить. Можно еще кучу условий домысливать.

Comment: @Alex R., Спасибо, вопрос решен благодаря Вам. Все работает именно так как нужно.